# .so (shared libraries) in third party jar file does not get into apk in android studio everything else go into it

Tags: android, c, android-studio, jar, apk

I have a third party jar file with .so files, dll files, data files and java class files under a multi-level subdirectory. When I build apk in Android Studio, it pulls everything else except the .so files. If I change the extension of .so file to .so.1 (used jar utility to extract third party jar file to change the extension)it pulls it in.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apicatjnovas"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk true
        includeInBundle true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar','.so'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation files('libs/jnovas_hp.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

---

ndk version - 21.1.6352462

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks